# Calculated Column for first 5 working days in each month

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I wanted to do calculated column in my calendar table in Power BI. The calculated column should show "1" for the first 5 working days in each month in the calendar table, the  rest of the days should be "0" . I tried to come out with the formula shown below

tick = CALCULATE(COUNT('Calendar'[Weekend - weekday]), 'Calendar'[IsWorkingDay] = TRUE)

[image: Calendar table]

But it shows "1" for all the working days but the desire output is the first 5 working days of each month. Anyone could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is your original table with new column for `Weekday-weekend`, you can calculate the new column to display 0 for first five working days using `rankx & If`, followed by 0 and blank for other case, here is the dax formula:

**Remark**: Both `1` and `0` need to with quotation mark, as using with `""` without convert to string will cause `Data is variant type` error.

```
tick1 = 
var rank1 = RANKX(FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Weekday-Weekend] = "Weekday" && Sheet1[Period] = EARLIER(Sheet1[Period]) ),Sheet1[Day],,ASC)
return
IF(Sheet1[Weekday-Weekend] = "Weekday" && rank1 >=1 && rank1 <=5, "1", 
    IF(Sheet1[Weekday-Weekend] = "Weekday", "0",""))
```

**The table with add column**

[image]

Comment: Hi , there it didnt work for me may be caused I have few years in the calendar table eq. 2016,2017 and 2018

Comment: This is the link to the power bi file that I am trying to solve
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OOTMF82fgUPLerR5Qq8Tfxz28b7d8GId/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You may check my edited answer, I include additional `filter in Rankx`, then it work for cross year also, accept if helping :)